# Nested for loop python (Summation/Math)

Tags: python, for-loop, math

My professor gave me rather unclear descriptions for some assignments with summation. I'm just wondering if I've got the right idea using nested `for` loops or if I'm way off? I've posted an image of said assignment below.

[image: Assignment]

```
def c(n):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        for j in range(1, n+1):
            sum = sum + i*j

    return sum
```

Comment: Yes, that is right. You could also do that in a one-liner using a generator expression: `sum(i*j for i in range(1, n+1) for j in range(1, n+1))`. There also is an easier math expression for that: `(n*(n+1)//2)**2`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for loops here:

```
def c(n):
    return (n**2 + n)**2 / 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This is equal to

```
1*(1+2+....+n) + 2*(1+2+....+n) + 3*(1+2+.....+n)+.....+n*(1+2+....n)
```

which is equal to

```
(1+2+....+n)*(1+2+.....+n)
```

which is:

```
square of sum of 1 to n = (n(n+1)/2)**2
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone probably stumbled upon here looking for how to use brute force nested for loops to find if two elements in an array equal a given sum. If so then this is your lucky day!

```
array2 = [1, 2, 4, 4]
sum_two = 8  

def two_equals_sum(array, sum):
  for i in range(len(array)-1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(array)):
      if array[i]+array[j]==sum:
        return print(f"{array[i]} + {array[j]} = {sum}!!!!")

  return print(f"There is no combination of numbers in array what equal {sum}")
two_equals_sum(array2,sum_two)
```

This will return 4+4=8. Hope this helped someone!